# nodejs API fs.fsync(fd, callback)

Tags: javascript, node.js

What's ths use of `fs.fsync(fd, callback)` in nodejs API?

---

`fs.fsync(fd, callback)`

> Asynchronous fsync(2).
>
> No arguments other than a possible exception are given to the completion callback.

`fs.fsyncSync(fd)`

> Synchronous fsync(2).

[Node.js API docs for `fs.fsync`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_fsync_fd_callback)

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/2/fsync

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fs.fsync` is just an asynchronous node wrapper for unix's `fsync`. Notice there's also an `fs.fsyncSync`, which is just the synchronous version. They just happen to be named in a confusingly standard manner.

http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?fsync+2

http://linux.die.net/man/2/fsync

Comment: Node API docs should consider at least linking like you did. It would be to assume all node developers where prior linux sys-admins. They must also assume that if we don't know what the linux command does that we'd look it up, so why not save us a couple keystrokes and give an adequate link describing the function.